# R create empty dataframe with header vector

Tags: r

How i can create empty dataframe with column name where column is a vector any length

```
c("A","B","C")
```

Im try

```
df<-data.frame()
colnames(df)<-c("A","B")
```

But is not working

Comment: Why do you need an empty data.frame? You can do this: `df <- data.frame(A = numeric(n), B = character(n), C = logical(n))` for any `n`.

Comment: `data.frame(A = c(), B = c())`

Comment: @RonakShah Have you checked the output?

Comment: As @Roland said, you will virtually never need to do something similar.

Comment: @nicola I have actually used this in production code. It's not the most efficient strategy to fill a data.frame in a loop, but the code is easy to read and understand.

Comment: @akrun yes, it gives data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Comment: But, it also doesn't show any names, i.e. the OP wanted to have A, B in the output as columns, here you have 0 variables and 0 observations. `str(data.frame(A = c(), B = c()))
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables`

Comment: @Roland I think that this kind of practices must be discouraged as much as possible... One reason why people say "R is slow" it's because codes are full of loop with `rbind(new,oldDF)`, which is basically the less efficient thing you can do in R (and, as far as I'm concerned not so much readable either). Of course, everyone of us used something similar in any environment I guess...

Comment: @nicola I never said I grow anything in a loop. Pre-allocate and fill.

Comment: @Roland Ah ok, maybe a misunderstanding. My "never need" was referring to create an empty `data.frame`. If preallocated is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
x <- LETTERS[1:3]
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(,0,length(x)))
names(df) <- x

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 0 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ A: logi 
#  $ B: logi 
#  $ C: logi
```

With OP's vector:

```
x <- c("field1","field2", "field3")
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(,0,length(x)))
names(df) <- x
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 0 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ field1: logi 
#  $ field2: logi 
#  $ field3: logi
```

Comment: For example im have vector c("field1","field2, filed3")

Comment: With a line: `as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=length(x),dimnames=list(NULL,x)))`

Comment: @nicola feel free to edit.

Comment: A comment is more than enough. I upvoted your answer, but I felt almost guilty, because I hate this practice in R (allocating empty objects and then let them grow) :)

Comment: @nicola Yes, I understand this. I personally don't proceed this way.

Comment: I believe that there are cases where this can be useful. Imagine for example the case where you want to generate a table (dataframe) where each row is the result of calculations performed on temporary data retrieved from an external source. In such a situation you may not know at the beginning the number of rows that your resulting data frame will have. I think that `rbind`ing each row, starting with an empty dataframe with named columns, would make sense there.

Comment: @RHertel No, guess a reasonable size, (over-)allocate that, grow in chunks only if needed, subset to the final size in the end.

Comment: @RHertel If you know the number of iterations (as one usually does), you allocate a `list` before in which you put the `data.frame` returned from the external source. At the end of the loop, you `rbind` them all together with `do.call`. Or do like Roland suggested.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(vector(),ncol=3))
colnames(df1) <-c("A","B","C")
df1
#[1] A B C
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```